# Chart.js 2.6.0 options / scales / xAxis / gridLines doesn't work for me?

Tags: chart.js

I want to remove the grid lines from a Chart.js 2.6.0 (Chart.bundle.js) line chart. It appears however that the entire gridLines key doesn't work for me.

Code snippet:

```
var options = {
  scales: {
    xAxis: [
      {
        gridLines: {   // does that work?!
          display: false,
        },
      },
    ],
    yAxis: [
      {
        gridLines: {
          display: false,
        },
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

I also tried to change color or pattern of grid lines, just to see if it works. Nothing inside the gridLines key had any effect on them.

Is there a bug, or I am lacking sleep too badly?

Answer (score 0):

`xAxes`  not 
`xAxis`

you spelled the properties wrong under `scales`

Comment: Other properties of xAxis and yAxis work. Could you be more specific, please?